# VSCode docker dev container can't access ~/.ssh

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I need access to `/home/vscode/.ssh/` so the tools I am using can use my ssh key, however I can't seem to change the permissions.

I build the container like so:

```
# other steps

COPY id_rsa /home/vscode/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /home/vscode/.ssh/id_rsa \
  && touch /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts \
  && ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts

# other steps
```

This grabs my `id_rsa` from my local directory and adds it into the docker container so I can keep using my existing SSH key.

I then try and use a tool like terraform to execute a command that clones in some code from a repository that is setup with my SSH key.

```
$ terraform plan

ERRO[0001] 1 error occurred:
        * error downloading 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/example/example.git?ref=master': /usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into '/workspaces/example'...
Failed to add the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts (/home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts).
Load key "/home/vscode/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

How can I correctly setup access in my Dockerfile? I can't even run `ssh-kegyen`!

```
$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/vscode/.ssh/id_rsa): 
/home/vscode/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Saving key "/home/vscode/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: Permission denied
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After several attempts at overriding user permissions in the Dockerfile I came to find out the user is set from the `devcontainer.json` file.

Simply go to the bottom where it sets the`"remoteUser": "vscode"` and comment it out.

This will now set the user as `root`. For local development this is perfect and should cause no issues. I can now utilise the SSH key as well as anything else previously locked off.

```json
// .devcontainer/devcontainer.json

{
    "name": "Ubuntu",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        // Update 'VARIANT' to pick an Ubuntu version: focal, bionic
        "args": { "VARIANT": "focal" }
    },

    "settings": {},

    "extensions": [],

    // "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that every file you touch will be owned by root, so if you do this, the user which you log in as in the first place to do development, can't touch the files at all, meaning even git commands are unlikely to work outside the dev container.

The reason the `remoteUser` field should be set is to preserve permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is occurring because the command is executed from a directory (`/workspaces`) that is not writable by non-admin users. VS Code creates this directory automatically and uses it as the start-up directory when you open a new terminal session.

In my case (Ubuntu 22.04), the issue is probably related to Docker being run in rootless mode. For some reason, VS Code is not able to bind the user to the local user outside the container, but instead it is bound to the root user. Setting the `"remoteUser"` or `"containerUser"` properties to `vscode` in `devcontainer.json` does not help, neither does setting the `USER vscode` in `Dockerfile`.

There are two ways to circumvent the problem after the build.

1. Change the permissions of the workspace directory:

```
sudo chown -R vscode:vscode /workspaces
terraform plan
```

On my local machine, this has the unfortunate consequence of modifying the owner to a nonexistent user. This is fine however, as long as the files are always modified inside the dev container only.

2. Copy the workspace directory to the home directory:

```
cp -R /workspaces $HOME
cd $HOME/workspaces
terraform plan
```

This way commands which create or modify files can be run from the terminal, but the files in the home directory are not visible in the VS Code workspace, so the convenience of using Dev Containers is lost. This method is just included as a workaround.

Unfortunately I have not found a way to incorporate these steps into the build of the container.

To change the owner of the SSH directory:

```
sudo chown -R vscode:vscode /home/vscode/.ssh
```

Or add this step to the `Dockerfile` after copying the SSH key (run as root):

```
RUN chown -R vscode:vscode /home/vscode/.ssh
```